# What is the mime type for .py files?

Tags: wordpress, mime-types

I have a WordPress site and in order to be able to upload python files I need to know the file's mime type. What is the mime type of a Python file? All I found was how to find the mime type of other files in python.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should be `application/x-python-code` or `text/x-python`.

Comment: for example, `.py` is `text/x-python` and `.pyc` is `application/x-python-code`. ref. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=235663#5