# "text/x-script.phyton" mime-type for a .py file

Tags: mime-types

An IT system gives my browser the mime-type `text/x-script.phyton` for a `.py` file. I take it that it is a typo and [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614485/what-is-the-mime-type-for-py-files) suggests `application/x-python-code` for `.pyc` files and `text/x-python` for `.py` files

Googling on `text/x-script.phyton` gives no less than over 1,000 hits, while typo-corrected `text/x-script.python` only gives around 7 times more,  `application/x-python-code` only 1,800 hits(!) and `text/x-python` gives over 47,000 hits.

I take it that `text/x-script.phyton` is "just" a strangely common typo?